# EC2 Instances to Automatically join AD hosted in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to know if there is an approach to automatically join an EC2 instance (launched via ElasticBeantalk) to an Active Directory already hosted in an EC2 Windows Server.

Following this document below I could see that is possible using AD Connector or AWS Simple AD (either will give a "directoryId)," but in my case, the AD already is hosted in an EC2.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-your-ec2-instances-to-automatically-join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following the same path - but instead of relying to the default SSM document for Managed AD, you should create a custom one.
In it, you can omit the directory id and rely on DNS name / IP address of your EC2 AD and respective domain name, username and password with which you join.

This approach is partially described in the [following blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain-with-parameter-store-and-amazon-ec2-systems-manager-documents/). It has an actual SSM document as a CloudFormation stack which you can use as a base.

In order to fully automate it you can create an Amazon EventBridge rule that will be looking for EC2 Launch instance events and has SSM Run Command as a target (Run Command can start your custom SSM document). There are some dedicated Beanstalk events that may be useful in this regard as well.